# Win 7 64-bit slow during software raid 1 resyncing

Tags: windows-7, performance, software-raid

I read about the slow resyncing here: https://serverfault.com/questions/107636/how-to-view-status-of-software-raid-1-resynching

I have a different question: not only is my resyncing slow; but during the resyncing, my entire system responds extremely slow. Is this normal, or is this indication that there is something wrong with my computer?

Shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is expected behavior, a resync requires the entire contents of your hard drive to be read and copied to the other drive. This is going to put considerable IO load on your drive until the resync is complete.